# How to open links in new window ONLY IF the check box is checked

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function

Here is what i have so far. I have it so they open in new windows, but i want it only if the check box is checked...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script>
    function new() {
       if ( document.getElementById('checkbox').checked )
            window.open( 'y', 'n', 't', 'New Window' );
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }

    var OpenNew = document.getElementById('opennew');
    OpenNew.addEventListener('click', OpenWin, false );
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>
<form name="test">
<p>Open link in a new window &nbsp; <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="check" /></p>
</form>
</p>
<p>
<h2>My favorite Websites to visit</h2>
<a href="http://www.youtube.com" target="new" id="y">Youtube</a><br />
<a href="http://www.newegg.com" target="new" id="n">Newegg</a><br />
<a href="http://www.twitch.tv" target="new" id="t">Twitch.tv</a><br />
</p>












</body>

</html>
```

I am unsure how to actually do the if statement if it is checked then open. It does currently open in a new tab.. i just need it to be only when its checked.

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: the javascript is broken, you have the `else` outside the function

Comment: what should happen if the checkbox is unchecked?

Comment: @Einacio This is a great example of why javascript style bracketing can be misleading/difficult to read.

Comment: I dont think the "javascript" bracketing style can be blamed as to why this doesn't work...  thats the least of his worries here

Comment: @cowls It is just something to note for people who are new to javascript and come from java/C style brackets.  It is pretty clear that there was some confusion in his original code (in addition to other, more obvious issues).

Comment: Very true, though at least Java has the same bracketing style

Comment: Ah, I stand corrected.

Comment: @jbaum012 A valid point none the less, especially for beginners to look out for

Comment: @cowls, it was my intention to delete the comment to boaz all the time - I just couldt clarify it in that way in a comment.

Comment: @davidkonrad It would still be useful to provide details as to the issues it would cause and in which IE versions, as I too am curious

Answer (score 0):

Not going to rewrite it for you but can hopefully set you on the right path.

Firstly, use `target="_blank"` to open in a new window, and `target="_self"` to open in same window.

All you need to do, is add an event listener to the `<a>` tags that simply checks whether the checkbox is checked and then sets the target attribute accordingly.

I suggest reading up on Javascript event listeners first.

JQuery will make this simpler, but it might be nice to understand the Javascript before moving onto using JQuery.

Some useful links

[Adding Event Listeners on Elements - Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445207/adding-event-listeners-on-elements-javascript)

[check if checkbox is checked javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887360/check-if-checkbox-is-checked-javascript)

http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/HTML/Changethetargetattributeofalink.htm

Comment: It is target=_blank, not target="_blank" (dont use quotes)

Comment: @davidkonrad I'm curious, what are you basing this on?

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>Open link in a new window &nbsp; <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="check" onclick="ss()"/></p>

<span id="w">Youtube</span><br />
<span id="qq">Newegg</span><br />
<span id="aa">Twitch.tv</span><br /> 

<script>
  function ss() {
    if (document.getElementById('checkbox').checked) {

      for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        var clear = document.getElementsByTagName("span")[i]
        clear.innerHTML = "";
      }

      var d = document.getElementById("w");
      var ele = document.createElement("a");
      var t = document.createTextNode("Youtube");
      ele.setAttribute('href', 'http://www.youtube.com');
      ele.appendChild(t);
      d.appendChild(ele);

      var d2 = document.getElementById("qq");
      var ele2 = document.createElement("a");
      var t2 = document.createTextNode("Newrag");
      ele2.setAttribute('href', 'http://www.newegg.com');
      ele2.appendChild(t2);
      d2.appendChild(ele2);

      var d3 = document.getElementById("aa");
      var ele3 = document.createElement("a");
      var t3 = document.createTextNode("Twich.tv");
      ele3.setAttribute('href', 'http://www.twitch.tv');
      ele3.appendChild(t3);
      d3.appendChild(ele3);

    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: ooh i forgot to add ele.setAttribute('target','_blank'); in each element creation. thanks