# Javascript Random Phrase From List

Tags: javascript, html

For my website, I am trying to make a button where every time a press a button a different quote comes up. I have made a separate document to make this. I am not very experienced at javascript, so please help. 
This is my HTML:

```
    <button">Change Quote</button>
    <p id="test"></p>
```

I am aiming to give each quote a number value from one to ten so its random. Also, when I click the button the p changes. Thanks.

EDIT: Is there any way to have it cycle through? For instance, once I get the first quote, can it go onto the second?

new JS:

```
    var quotes = [
  "I am Bob",
  "I am smart",
  "I am independent",
  "I am bringing change",
];

document.getElementById("changeQuote").addEventListener("click", function() {
var q = quotes[ Math.floor( Math.random() * quotes.length ) ];
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = q;
```

Thanks again.

Comment: Where are the quotes stored? If you put them in an array in your JS file it would be trivial to select one from the array at [random](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) each time a button is clicked.

Comment: @nnnnnn I'm not sure how to, maybe in a array? Not sure.

Comment: 1. [Create an array of quotes.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746725/create-a-javascript-array-containing-1-n) 2. [Add a click handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445207/adding-event-listeners-on-elements-javascript). 3. [Select a random element from the array.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915096/get-random-item-from-javascript-array) 4. [Update the content of the target element.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121817/how-do-i-replace-text-inside-a-div-element#answer-121824)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, store the quotes in an array, then add a click handler that selects at random from that array.

Give your button an id, so it can easily be selected from JS:

```
<button id="changeQuote">Change Quote</button>
```

Then something like this, using the [`Math.random()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random):

```
var quotes = [
      "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.",
      "Look out! There are llamas!",
      "No, really, don't get up.",
      "Whatever",
      "Etc."    
    ];

document.getElementById("changeQuote").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var q = quotes[ Math.floor( Math.random() * quotes.length ) ];
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = q;     
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9pqqmnrs/

Further reading:

- [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)
- [`Math.floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor)
- [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Answer (score 0):

Easy way:

```
<p id="test"></p>

    <script>
        var quotes = ["quote 1", "quote 2", "quote 3", "quote 4", "quote 5"];
        var index = Math.floor((Math.random() * quotes.length)); 
        document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = quotes[index];

    </script>
```

Explanation: Quotes are stored as array. Math functions used to determine which random number will be generated based on the quotes array length. See also: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp