# on click fire addEventListener

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is basic but I have no idea how to do this.

There is an addEventListener that fires on page load.

```
var imgcnvs = document.createElement('canvas');
var imagecxt = imgcnvs.getContext('2d');

window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    //do something
}, false);
```

How can I convert `window.addEventListener('load', function(){` to work when $('#startBtn') is clicked? `

Comment: 'click' event https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events

Comment: @MilindAnantwar thanks. How can I convert `window.addEventListener('load', function(){` to a click event?

Comment: Click on what element exactly. Can you try to be more descriptive and precise in what's your issue and what you actually need?

Comment: So you want to fire an event when the page loads?..

Comment: @Bekki: change `load` with `click`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan thanks. I've edited my post. see last sentence.

Comment: @Bekki have you used Goog or read the jQuery documentation on how to add a click event on an ID element?

Comment: @Bekki for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445207/adding-event-listeners-on-elements-javascript - Please, before asking new questions make sure there's no duplicate ones.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan. Thanks. I did not come across that post while googling. :)

Comment: I don't quite believe you did your research before asking. Even the MDN documentation for `addEventListener` has plenty of examples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener. Take care and happy coding!

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thanks again. :) tc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get your target element, using `document.getElementById` for instance, and then attach the event listener to it. As follows:

```
document.getElementById("startBtn").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  // Do something
}, false);
```

Comment: thanks :) Looks good.

Answer (score 3):

```
$( "#startBtn" ).click(function() {
    //dosomething
 });
```

Please read the [jquery documentation.](https://api.jquery.com/click/)

Comment: who downvoted? the `jquery` tag was added to the question.. this is a possible solution..

Comment: @MateiMihai dont know i get that alot.

Comment: Thanks. I was actually looking for a pure js answer. Yours work too. :) #up-vote

Comment: @Bekki You've added the jquery tag.

Comment: @Bekki http://jsfiddle.net/lesson8/h4JXs/1/ for an example. If you google what you want for example jquery click you get an answer.